# How do I stop a button from scrolling to the top when clicked ? (Wordpress)

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress, button, scroll

I have this code for a button to show and hide a section in a Wordpress site. The problem is that I can't find a solution to stop it scrolling up when I click on the button.

This code is not mine, but from YouTube. The guy didn't know how to change it so that when we click on the button the page don't scroll to the top.

The code ".gopikachu" is link the a button widget on my site...

EDIT : I found the solution now ! The button itself was the problem. It had a "#" as its "URL link" --> That made the scroll up.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('.gopikachu').each(function(i) {
      $(this).click(function() {
        $('.pikachu').eq(i).toggle();
        $('.gopikachu');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.gopikachu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pikachu {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The important part here is the HTML, which you haven't included. We need to know what kind of element that `.gopikachu` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the solution !

It was not the HTML that was from, but the button widget itself !
It had a "#" as the description of it's "URL Link" !

---> and this "#" is the source of the Scolling up.

Thanks for the help. And I can now help 2 others persons in youtube that were searching for the solution

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).